# Getting this error while creating a recordSet in Dreamweaver - Using MAMP

Tags: php, database, phpmyadmin, dreamweaver, mamp

I get this error after installing mamp and setting up my site on dreamweaver. I connected to a database I created in phpMyAdmin, then i tried to create a recordSet for my application then i get this error.

While executing addDynamicSource in Recordset.htm, a JavaScript error occured.

Any idea anybody what this is and how to fix it. thanks

Answer (score 1):

you willo need to give more information if you want some one to answer that. maybe a copy of the access script without the link names and making sure your links are correct when an answer is given to see if you have script errors that you are noticing on compile. or maybe use a compiler that will seee these errors